# MOSS Configuration Failed to create sample data. User cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss

Looked all over the net for an answer to this; but it seems we are all asking the same question :(
The wizard fails at point 8 in the installation.

Log file says...
A SocketException was thrown with SocketError ConnectionRefused
08/26/2011 20:48:15  13  INF                              Connect has been refused for port 43171, so we will consider this a free port.  Exception thrown was SPException.  Exception message No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 169.254.199.201:43171, Exception type System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, Exception source System, Exception stack    at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEvaluatorModeProvisioning.GenerateUniquePort(Int32 maxTries, Int32 minimumPort, Int32 maximumPort).
08/26/2011 20:48:15  13  INF                              Adding port 43171 to the exclusion list so it is not chosen again
08/26/2011 20:48:15  13  INF                              Entering function SPEvaluatorModeProvisioning.AddExcludedPort
08/26/2011 20:48:15  13  INF                              Leaving function SPEvaluatorModeProvisioning.AddExcludedPort
08/26/2011 20:48:15  13  INF                            Leaving function SPEvaluatorModeProvisioning.GenerateUniquePort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dumped the Virtual PC and started from scratch using "How to Create a MOSS 2007 VPC Image: The Whole 9 Yards"
http://www.pptspaces.com/sharepointreporterblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=28
SharePoint is now running.